# How to detect background scanning of an Android Application?

Tags: java, android, background, location

I want to investigate some Applications on Google Play about their Wi-Fi/Location background scanning features. Is there any tools to implement that?

I am now using Battery Historian to check the GPS utilization. But it cannot show the Wi-Fi scanning in background. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Battery historian also shows wifi scans

Comment: @TimCastelijns Really? But I haven't seen the catalog of wifi scan in html file. Does that means there's no wifi scan in that period?

Comment: It's possible. During my tests I would scan for wifi about once every 5 minutes

Comment: @TimCastelijns Actually, my test lasts for about 1 hour. It should be some wifi scans during test period.

Comment: @TimCastelijns I'm thinking if there's some debugging log in Android studio that can record all Application behaviours.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Battery Historian to detect the Wi-Fi scanning in the background. They are shown only on Android 8 and later assuming that you run your test on Android 8 device with high accuracy location mode on and Wi-Fi scanning option is activated.

[image]